# HttpApplication.Request value change while inside Application_AuthenticateRequest

Tags: asp.net

Today we got several errors from our production web server that indicated that we had a null reference while calling Request.CurrentExecutionFilePath.StartsWith. This is occurring inside our Application_AuthenticateRequest in Global.asax.cs.

After some reading of code, I found that the previous line calls Request.CurrentExecutionFilePath.StartsWith successfully.

So, that means to me that the value of Request.CurrentExecutionFilePath has changed from one line to the next. How is this possible? How can it be prevented/fixed?

Answer (score 0):

Does your authentication scheme redirect anywhere if the auth fails? If so, and if it is a `Server.Transfer` instead of a `Response.Redirect`, then I could imagine a case where `ExecutionFilePath` changes, though not to `null`. At any rate, the easiest test case would probably be to try logging in but giving it the incorrect password.